# Ruby on Rails disabled field in form select not working

Tags: ruby, forms, select, ruby-on-rails-4, disabled-input

```
<%= f.select :minutes, options_for_select([['1 hour', 60], ['1 hour and a half', 90], ['2 hours', 120]][0..(@minutes_to_schedule/30-2)], 60), {}, {disabled: true} %>
```

I checked the Form Helper API but despite following suit my options were still not disabled, is there anything I'm overlooking?  I looked at the other stacked posts and it doesn't seem like I'm doing anything wrong

```
   <%= form_for(@session_date, html: {class: 'no_custom'}) do |f| %>

      <%= f.hidden_field :student_id, value: @student.id %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag 'from', schedule_student_path(id: @student.id) %>          
      <div id="appointment_display"></div>         
      <input id="appointment_at" type="datetime-local"  name="appointment[at]" step="900" min= "some_time" max="max_time" required="required" placeholder="Use Chrome!" style="width: auto; display: none;"/>
      <br/>
      <div id="appointment_location_display"></div> 
      <br/>
      <%= f.select :minutes, options_for_select(@appointment_time_options, 60) %>
      <br/> 
      <%= f.collection_select(:location_id, Location.order('city, state, address'), :id, :name, {}, {class: 'dont_display'}) %>
      <%= f.submit 'Create Appointment' %>
      <br/>

    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

**disabled: true** should be the 4th parameter

Check the definition below

```
options_from_collection_for_select(collection, value_method, text_method, selected = nil)
```

So, the correct way to do it ...

```
<%= f.select : minutes, options_for_select( ([['1 hour', 60], ['1 hour and a half', 90], ['2 hours', 120]]), {}, {}, { disabled: true } )%>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks correct.

When I copy/paste this:

```
<%= f.select : minutes, options_for_select([['1 hour', 60], ['1 hour and a half', 90], ['2 hours', 120]]), {}, { disabled: true }%>
```

Into a Rails app, the correct form element gets generated:

```
<select disabled="disabled" id="post_minutes" name="post[minutes]">
   <option value="60">1 hour</option>
   <option value="90">1 hour and a half</option>
   <option value="120">2 hours</option>
</select>
```

and the element is disabled like it should be. Is there any JS manipulating this field? Would you mind providing your whole form so I can help you out?

Comment: I edited my post to include the form I'm using.  I'm using jQuery to manipulate anything in the form with an ID